# Why does the browser still store my information even after i have gone incognito?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, identifier

I recently came across a website that was created for a marketing campaign. Basically, you have 3 tries a day where you can click on a button and stand to win prizes. (Don't worry I am savvy enough to know its not a scam :)

My question, is, it seems to know how many times i have played a day. After the third try, it doesn't allow me to click on it anymore. Normally, i would clear the cache and cookies and this restriction would be lifted. This is not the case here. I am not logged into Facebook or any other social media sites.

FWIW, i noticed a loading link that appears at the bottom of the page that goes something like "transferring data from res.id-linking.com" ... i am wondering if the browser has a unique identifier?

I am not sure if i can post the link of the campaign page here, but it's by a reputable company.

Comment: Probably they're tracking your IP address.

Comment: Thank you.. The restriction didn't work when I tried different browsers.. But after the 3rd try on each browser, the restrictions were applied.

Answer (score 0):

Incognito mode doesn't mean you keep your moves private.   There are [many ways to recognise you](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/16548). For example, as miken32 mentioned in comment, they might track your IP.

> They will still be able to track you based on your IP-addresss and
>   your screensize, System Fonts, Browser Plugin Details, etc (see:
>   https://panopticlick.eff.org/ ) You just don't store browserhistory
>   including the caches and cookies in your browser after you leave the
>   "private session".

I recommend reading the whole linked question with answers about private modes in a browser.

Comment: Thank you.. The restriction didn't work when I tried different browsers.. But after the 3rd try on each browser, the restrictions were applied.